# Mule - how to configure an environment-specific external database in Mule Standalone

Tags: database, jdbc, database-connection, mule, environment

I'm building a Mule application that connects to an external database to retrieve some information that is injected into several of my flows. I've tested this locally with a MySQL database, configured using a `<jdbc:mysql-data-source>` connector.

The issue I have is that this app is being deployed to several environments (testing, production etc) and in each of those environments, the database type for this lookup database differs - for example, in one I am connecting to an Oracle database, and another a MySQL database.

Is there a way I can configure an environment-specific database connector in Mule - so for one environment I may use `<jdbc:mysql-data-source>`, and in another I may use `<jdbc:oracle-data-source>`? For info, I'm building my app using Maven. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several options

1) You can use two different files for each of the jdbc connectors.

You can configure in mule-deploy.properties for test environment:
config.resources=mule-config.xml,test-jdbc-config.xml
And for production environment
config.resources=mule-config.xml,prod-jdbc-config.xml

In each of those files you can define your database dependant connector (with the same name), and in mule-config you will reference the connector from your endpoints.

With this approach you will need two different applications for test and prod, because you need these two different mule-deploy.properties files.

Take a look at this docs: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deployment+Descriptor

2) You can use a generic jdbc connector referencing a bean where you define the JDBC URL (possible configuring it in a properties file or configuring it as a system property)

3) Create different Spring profiles for defining the beans for JDBC URL as explained here: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Regards.

Comment: Thanks @Ale. I think I'm going to explore your first option.